# Given two square points (x, y) find the other two to draw the square

Tags: java

I'm having difficulties to draw a square given two points only.

For example if I have A (4,4) and B (5,0) I need to draw the square by pressing SHIFT (the orientation of the square is given by the position of the mouse after SFHIT has been click).

I have the equation y = m*x + b of the line (4,4) -> (5,0) and I can know if the mouse is above or below the line in that specific moment.

My diffculty is to find the other two vertices, so that, I can draw the lines and have a square.

I know that this is more Maths than programming, or better, is all about maths, but i would apreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You need to find the four vertices of the square. The simplest way to do that is to look at the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) coordinates you have. Then you simply recombine them, so that your vertices must be (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y1), (x2, y2) if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: This problem is ill posed unless the square is aligned with the axes.  Two points only define a line.  Are we to assume that that line is a diagonal?

Comment: What do these points represent? If they're representing opposite corners, then you can't simply recombine xs and ys - consider the OP example. This will not be a square. Are these a corner and a center? Or are we finding a square with these corners, which will exist but may not have sides parallel to the axes?

Comment: this 2 points represents a line, the line can be horizontal (slope = 0) or diagonal (slope != 0) or vertical. An yes, they represent two corners, and my program has to draw the 3 left lines to complete the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do :

- compute the orientation vector V of the line passing by the point pointed by the mouse and orthogonal to the line (AB)
- normalize V
- compute A' (resp. B') the image of A (resp. B) by the translation of vector norm(AB).V
- draw the ABB'A' square

The resulting square will be oriented as what a user would naturally expect. The code could be something like that, with a custom `Point` class also used to represent vectors :

```
public void drawSquare(Point A, Point B, Point mouse) {
    // v is the normal vector or line (AB) which norm is distance(A,B)
    Point v = new Point(B.x - A.x,A.y- B.y);
    v       = v.dot(mouse.subtract(B)) < 0 ? v.opposite() : v;
    // translate A and B and draw the square
    draw(new Square(A,B,B.sum(v),A.sum(v)));
}
```

I hope there is no sign error !

Comment: thanks, i will try to understand 100% before implement.

Comment: If something seems wrong when you start implementing this, please tell me.